# pip for python3.5 broken Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, pip, python-3.5

I'm experiencing a strange issue with the pip(3).

I'm receiving this error when I performed any pip command like pip --version(or pip3 --version):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 6, in <module>
    import compileall
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/compileall.py", line 20, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Python version

```
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

~/ pip

pip          pip2         pip2.7       pip3         pip-compile  pip-sync
```

I've pip2.7 installed and is working well. I'm under Ubuntu 16.10 and I don't understand what is the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had the same problem. Replace the the line

```
raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
```

with

```
raise Exception(self._exception).with_traceback(self._traceback)
```

in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py

Comment: I am glad that it helped. I had had problems with this for a while and it was getting annoying but no one helped.

Comment: Thanks! My line was a little different: raise exception_type, self._exception, self._traceback

Comment: Note: you need to do this to make pip work at all, and then uninstall futures as misha pointed out.

Comment: @Matt the change to the library file should not be made, you have to do what the **mpenkov** has mentioned as Python 3.2 and higher has the futures library inbuilt and the module should not be installed. https://pypi.org/project/futures/

_This is a backport of the concurrent.futures standard library module to Python 2.

It does not work on Python 3 due to Python 2 syntax being used in the codebase. Python 3 users should not attempt to install it, since the package is already included in the standard library._

Answer (score 14):

The futures library back-ports some Python 3 features so that they can be used in Python 2.

Unless you absolutely must have it installed, you can just:

```
pip uninstall futures
```

to remove it from your Python 3 virtual environment.

Comment: If anyone runs with into the same error with pip3 during uninstall, try with sudo: `sudo -H pip3 uninstall futures`

Comment: Uhh. So is Futures just broken? I don't even know how this got installed in the first place.